# Mask remote request to Tornado server as local

Tags: security, curl, request, http-post, tornado

I have a Tornado server running on some port

And if I make a request via browser to non existing url, Tornado prints:

```
WARNING:tornado.access:404 POST /some_url/ (MY.REAL.IP) 0.64ms python
```

But I noticed another 404 error done via localhost:

```
WARNING:tornado.access:404 POST /some_url/ (127.0.0.1) 0.64ms python
```

Is it possible in theory, that this request was done by some "cool hacker" from remote server using `curl --resolve` or something?

Answer (score 1):

The only way this address should be spoofable would be if you set `xheaders=True` in your `HTTPServer` constructor. If you use `xheaders=True`, you should also be using a frontend proxy that sanitizes headers appropriately so it will not allow `X-Real-IP` headers from outside sources.